# How to prevent duplicate content penalty in this special case

Tags: seo, duplicate-content, canonical-url

I am building a micro-blogging page where everyone can post about everything and it's shown on some kind of a post-it-wall.

Older posts disappear fast (depending how much is posted, of course). Users can't access a single post with links on the page itself, but I've implemented an algorithm to have a single post on top of all the other posts with a direct link which I will include in a dynamically generated xml-sitemap.

The links look like this:

```
www.site.com/text-of-post-a-123
www.site.com/text-of-post-b-124
```

etc.

Now I fear that my pages will get a duplicate content warning, as the only difference between those 2 pages will be the first post, the following posts would be the same (given the exact same time of a request).

I know about the canonical tag, but that's dealing with the whole page. Is there any way I can show SEs, that only a part of my page is relevant?

Thank you for your ideas!

Comment: Is there a reason why you've designed your URL structure like this, rather than say a unique URL for each post?

Comment: Thanks to everyone for your input. I think I'll just use SEs disabilities to crawl AJAX-loaded content and lazy-load the rest of the posts via AJAX. A normal user won't notice much and there's even the advantage that the important content he was interested in when clickin on the SERP will be loaded a bit faster. Do you agree?

Comment: @nathangiesbrecht please re-read, there is a URL for each post, but this points to the main site which then will display as usual EXCEPT that the url-referenced post will be displayed above everything else (without that URL, the post would be lower on the page or won't show at all)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your site's layout completely from your description, but to address your question: search engines index pages, not specific parts of a page.

The Google's Webmaster Tools help document on [duplicate content](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=66359) is pretty comprehensive about how to manage this. In cases where there isn't any directive like [canonicalization](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139066), it will chose one URL over the other, and you run the risk of your site not being indexed if deemed deceptive or manipulative.

If the majority of content remains the same between pages and only a portion of the page changes, you can [iframe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_element#Frames) the content that doesn't change, and if the iframe is crawled, the search engine will attribute its content to the originating page instead of the containing page (the page in which the iframe appears). In this case, you should only add a canonical link to the originating page (the iframe source).